# Why does the Android emulator not register an externally included jar?

Tags: android, eclipse, jar, gson

I working in Eclipse, and I'm attempting to use GSON. I added the gson-2.2.2.jar as external jar in Eclipse. I then run the Android app in the emulator. I get "Could not find class 'com.google.gson.Gson', referenced from method com.mycompany.myapp.MyMethod".

What could be causing this?

Comment: Can you post your code please?

Answer (score 4):

Copy the jar file into the `libs/` folder of your project directory.
I had similar error and copying jar file to `libs/` fixed the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Right Click project -> Build Path -> Configure Build Path
In the Libraries Tab is where you add your external jar.
Make sure you then go to the Order and Export tab and make sure the box is checked because that is the build path order. And like SRN said, you should just add it to your libs folder and then reference it locally instead of externally.

Comment: Once you're in the Java Build Path tab, click on "Add External JARs..." to add your GSON .jar file.

Comment: You do not explicitly add JARs to the build path as of the R17 version of the tools. Simply having them in `libs/` is sufficient.

Comment: That's just how I have always done it and its always worked, so I'm not complaining.